# How to round only some corners of an image with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

I want to round only the two bottom corners of my image.
I found a lot of examples in Objective-C and almost nothing with Swift.

This is what I found but it gives me an error:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()

        rectShape.bounds = self.image.frame
        rectShape.position = self.image.center
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.image.bounds,     byRoundingCorners: .BottomLeft | .BottomRight, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath

        self.image.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

        self.image.layer.mask = rectShape
```

The error I get is in the line with `rectShape.path` and tells me that

```
No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'UIRectCorner'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In swift changes the way we put things like this. In objective c it was ok to write a | to separate options, but in swift you have to put it like an array:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()

    rectShape.bounds = self.image.frame
    rectShape.position = self.image.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.image.bounds,     byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).CGPath

    self.image.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

    self.image.layer.mask = rectShape
```

Comment: Thanks i tested and it is working! Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Make sure to add this code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` I tried using this in viewDidLoad and was giving me issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3 ))
```

Comment: This would work, but please add explanation text to explain why it works to allow others to understand your answer.